# Prove that $ \frac{1}{\left|z(1-z)\right|}<\frac{1}{\left|z-\frac{1}{2}\right|^2}$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, inequality, complex-numbers

If $z=x+iy$ is complex number such that $0<x<1$ and $y>13$ then prove that $$ \frac{1}{\left|z(1-z)\right|}<\frac{1}{\left|z-\frac{1}{2}\right|^2}$$

We have $$ \frac{1}{\left|z(1-z)\right|}=\frac{1}{\left|(z-\frac{1}{2})^2-\frac{1}{4}\right|}$$
So we get by reverse triangle inequality $$ \frac{1}{\left|z(1-z)\right|}\leq\frac{1}{\left||z-\frac{1}{2}|^2-\frac{1}{4}\right|}$$
Thank you.

Comment: The hypothesis $0 \lt x \lt 1$ is equivalent to $\lvert z +\overline{z} -1\rvert \lt 1$. Maybe it helps.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net Thanks. But I don't know how to use the inequality here. Please write as an answer.

Comment: This will not be true, even for $y=0$, in which case considering $x$ arbitrarily close to $1$.

Comment: @Feng Right, or for $\,z \to 0\,$ either.

Comment: You have not used the fact that $z$ lives in the region specified. That seems important since the inequality is false in general. Can you say anything about $\arg\left(z-\frac12\right)$ and $\left|z-\frac12\right|$ for $z$ in that region?

Comment: Also, you are trying to find when $\left|\,\left(z-\frac12\right)^2-\frac14\,\right|\gt\left|\,\left(z-\frac12\right)^2\,\right|$. What can you say about the $w$ for which $\left|w-\frac14\right|\gt|w|$?

Comment: It appears that you have tried to use the reverse triangle inequality. That didn't seem to lead anywhere. Have you tried anything else? If not, it might help add [context](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9960) to mention from where this problem came, or what other things are being discussed in the book you are using or class you are taking. Otherwise, people are encouraged [not to answer PSQs](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards).

Comment: @robjohn Thank you. Please write an answer. I am not able to think on the problem.

Comment: If you cannot think on the problem, try answering some of the questions I mention: the origin of the problem, the topics being discussed in the book or class, etc. Those will help add context to your question. Once you add some context, people can answer.